# How to insert "#" comment off to the specific keyword by using Tcl?

Tags: tcl

Is that any way in TCL to insert the (#) comment off by searching cfg keyword?

-->Before

```
abcd abcd abcd
cfgabc abcd abcd
cfgcdd abc abc
abcd abcd abcd
cfgabc abcd abcd
```

-->After run the tcl

```
abcd abcd abcd
#cfgabc abcd abcd
#cfgcdd abc abc
abcd abcd abcd
#cfgabc abcd abcd
```

Comment: Suggest you look at `string match` for finding the cfg prefix, and `lmap` for iterating matches and modify the string as you find them: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M35 https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.html

Answer (score 3):

you can use [regsub](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.html):
`regsub -all {cfg} $str {#cfg}`

***EDIT***
For finding cfg anywhere in the string and commenting this line (as requested in the comments):
`regsub {(.*)cfg(.*)} $str {#\1cfg\2}`
e.g.

> set str "bla lkjhcfglkj"
> bla lkjhcfglkj
> regsub {(.*)cfg(.*)} $str {#\1cfg\2}
> #bla lkjhcfglkj

This is much riskier and requires more attention and caution.

Comment: There's also `{\mcfg}` if you only want to match when cfg appears at the beginning of a word instead of anywhere in the string.

Comment: Hmm, the answer very helpful, but How to insert the # in front of the line below want search the cfg but want comment off whole line?
#abcd cfgabc

Comment: @WTingChong, that seems to be a different question

Comment: @WTingChong as glenn wrote - this is a different question, in the current question cfg is always at the beginning of the line. I'll edit the answer for your general case

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the three letters `cfg` at the beginning of a line, that's pretty easy to do with `regsub`. In particular, the `-line` option helps a lot with this.

```
regsub -all -line {^cfg} $str "#cfg"
```

Note that caution should be taken with this sort of thing: it's extremely easy to either over- or under-match lines. Check the results by hand! (Hopefully it'll be easier than doing lots of edits by hand.)